# Autowired component always null

Tags: spring

My autowired component is always null no matter what annotation I use. I am not creating a new object so I can't figure out what the reason is. What can I try to resolve this?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.service"})
@Path("/my-app")
public class MyApplication {

  @Autowired
  MyService service; ---- THIS IS ALWAYS NULL

  @GetMapping("/example")
  public String example() {
    service.doStuff();
  }
}

@Service
public interface MyService() {

  public void doStuff();
}

@Component
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService() {

  @Autowired
  MyRepository repo;

  public void doStuff() {
    repo.findByName( "steve" );
  }
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<My, Long> {
  List<My> findByName( String name );
}
```

Comment: Remove the Service annotation from the interface. Replace the @Component on the impl with the Service. Also create a separate class to application and controller.
Please fix your example code too, there are a lot of compile error.

Comment: @zlaval, that didn't help. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'v created a sample app to you, maybe you can find what is the bug in your example: https://github.com/zlaval/very-simple-springapp

Or you should give more information (maybe your service is out of the component scan targets etc)